# iPhone Function Symbol Not Found

Tags: iphone

This is a lame question; but I couldn't find a way. In an iPhone application I am creating a function in .m file:

```
- (void) xx {
....
return;
}
```

and in .h file a declare it as:

```
- (void) xx;
```

However when I call the function in anywhere, I get linker error (symbol not found) in compile process. Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling the "xx" function? The construction of your function looks OK. Your problem is probably related to when you try to call the function.

In the class that is calling your function "xx" try calling it via the following:

**[self xx];**